# Why do I have to re-login every 5 mins or so?

Tags: support, login

Why do I have to re-login every 5 mins or so? After which it's generally met with a page that states it's a suspicious attempt.

Comment: no IP has been the same for years.

Comment: Is it shared? Other people with the same IP address?

Comment: Try clearing out your cache and cookies - could be corrupt.

Comment: Nope, i'm the only one with this IP address.
I'll give that a shot.

Comment: If that doesn't work - please provide more details: browser, OS and versions. Also - if you have any browsers plugins/add-ons/extensions, disable them all and see if that helps.